# Excel sum on multiple conditions one logical

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

Column A has prices, B has names, C has a number. I need a sum of the prices next to my name if C>0 but SUMIFS doesn't seem to work with logic operators.

Comment: SUMIF function contain logic operator try to provide a sample about this problem, it will easier for us to provide a solution here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use strings or string concatenation to use inequalities.

Something like this:

`SUMIFS(sum_range,criteria_range,">0")`